# How to toggle ASG to use launch_configuration or launch_templated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-auto-scaling, terraform0.11

I am working on migrating our infrastructure code from launch_configuration to launch_template. I want to use either launch_configuration and launch_template based on the AWS region.

How can i use aws_autoscaling_group resource to pick launch_configuration or launch_template?

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg" {
launch_configuration = xyz

or 

launch_template {
 id = 123
 version = $LATEST
}
```

I could use dynamic block for launch_template block based on the condition but i am not able to figure out how to include or exclude launch_configuration argument based on the condition

Answer (score 0):

> how to include or exclude launch_configuration argument based on the condition

You do this with `null`:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg" {
   launch_configuration = var.use_lc ? aws_launch_configuration.lc.id : null
}
```

Comment: I am using Terraform v0.11.x and using null throwing error. * module.controller_asg.aws_autoscaling_group.asg: invalid variable syntax: "null". Did you mean 'var.null'? If this is part of inline `template` parameter
then you must escape the interpolation with two dollar signs.

Comment: launch_configuration = "${var.is_launch_template ? null : var.launch_config_id}"

Comment: @Karthik How come you are using tf 11? Your wrote that you can use dynamic blocks, which are not even supported in tf 0.11?

Comment: My bad, i couldn't use dynamic block either i was thinking TF version was 0.12